# Backup and restore depending databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, backup

I have 2 SQL Server databases, `Parent` and `Child`. Both are not always in the same server, but there is always a reference to `Parent` in the `Child` database using linked server. `Child` database makes changes to `Parent` database through stored procedures and synonyms, so both databases always are in the same 'state'.

The problem is that sometimes a client of my system makes a backup of only one of this databases, make some changes (that affects both databases), and then restore this backup. In that moment, both databases are not in the same 'state'.

I would like to know if this is happening, so when a user open the software using the `Child` database, I can show an error message.

I thought about setting up a Job, writing some kind of version number of both databases every `n` seconds, but this doesn't work, because this version number is base on time, not in changes made to the databases.

I was thinking too about a version number based on the replication log of the database, but I don't know much about the subject.

Comment: There really isn't much you can do here. You have two databases running on different servers.

Comment: Wath about if they where both in the same server?

Comment: There are different databases, it is not something that is going to be easy to do. You can't just have the database restore process throw an error because some other database is not the right version. You need to create a versioning system so that you can check the version number on both databases to ensure they are the same. But you can't prevent a restore from happening.

Comment: I don't want to prevent restore. I just want to know after a restore if this new database is in the same state than the other, so I can show a UI Error Message on my software. Actually my question maybe is about that versioning system you talk about. How to get a version number based on changes to the database and not to time.

Comment: Anything you do is going to be super brittle here. You could have a version number in both databases that you change when you release a software update. You could check to see if they match and if they don't display your message. There are so many way this kind of thing can break though.

Comment: A version number can't be based on software update, It must be on Data changes. A database is in a state different to the other if there is changes on the data, not only in the database structure.

Comment: Well then good luck. What you are asking for here is nearly impossible.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a job for them that does the restore and train them to run your job instead of a manual restore using SMS, then you can add a final step in the job that updates a "LastRestoreDateTime" column in a new table that you create... perhaps named "RestoreHistory".

Then when they launch the application you can check that value and know if you already handled this restore.  Throw the error if you haven't.  Continue as normal if you have.

This is just one of many possible ways.

That option does not check for data differences, however.

Option 2 would be to turn on CDC for Child database.  Then in you application startup routine for your app, you could grab the last record for each of your _CDC tables, and write some logic to compare with correcsponding Parent tables.

This is not entirely practical, but it achieves the request.

Answer (score 0):

For restoring the databases in the same consistent state, you need to backup the transaction files along with the data files.
This can be done using custom scripts or any 3rd party SQL backup tool like Acronis or Cloudberry backup for SQL servers which will allow you to take the system as well as DB backups for your server with ease.